# retrieving the value of the included html in struts2

Tags: struts2, include

I've included an html in my JSP
< s: include value="test.html" />. this test.html contains radio button. How do i retrieve the value of the radio button and pass it to action?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sradio-radio-button-example/

Answer (score 0):

Add this `<s:include />` tag in a form in your main page. e.g.

```
<s:form action="Welcome">
    <s:include value="test.jsp"></s:include>
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

test.jsp:

```
<input type="radio" value="abc" name="test" >abc</input>
<input type="radio" value="def" name="test" >def</input>
```

And in your Action named `Welcome` :

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
System.out.println(request.getParameter("test"));
```

You can get the value of your radio button. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:form action="sampleAction">
    <s:include value="yourjspfile.jsp"/>
    <s:submit />
</s:form>

yourjspfile.jsp

<s:textfield name="name" label="Enter your name"/>
```

You can specify the name property in your action class and can access it directly no need to get it from the request object.